# Disable TLS1.0 and TLS 1.1 through cPanel

Tags: https, apache2

I am using Apache and i have access of cPanel. I want to disable TLS1.0. I have  no idea how to do this. Can this done via cPanel?

Is there is any option how to do that?   Where do I need to change that?

Comment: Maybe somebody can answer you about whether it can be done through cPanel.  I don't use cPanel, so I don't know.    ServerFault has the answer to how to to do it through config files: [How can I disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 in apache?](https://serverfault.com/questions/848177/how-can-i-disable-tls-1-0-and-1-1-in-apache)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have access to WHM then its not possible to edit the Apache instance as you are sharing the same configuration with many other users.

*Generally this is found in*

> [Apache Configuration](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Adjust+Cipher+Protocols)
>
> Adjust Apache's protocol string in WHM's Global Configuration
>   interface (Home >> Service Configuration >> Apache Configuration >>
>   Global Configuration).

Which you would the use something like `-all +SSLv2 +SSLv3 +TLSv1.2`

But it can be done in cPanel but you would need to contact your web host because you need to edit the virtual host file.

> [Apache SSL Virtual Host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html)
>
> # be liberal in general SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+EXP:+eNULL

Then the above code you change to the Ciphers you want to use, you can find a list of the commands for [ciphers here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite).